# How to extract a graph out of Neo4J and reconstruct it in the programming language

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Consider I have a bunch of connected nodes in Neo4J, forming a tree or a graph or whatever, and I want to have them in the programming language that I'm using (I'm using Java but that's not important).

I know I can have them all with a single cypher query like this:

```
MATCH (n0:Root)-[:Child*0..]->(nx:Node) WHERE ID(n0) = 1 RETURN nx;
```

But the problem I have here is that once returned to Java, I don't know which node is connected to which! How can I return the data so I can reconstruct the graph in my programming language?

I can see that the Neo4J web interface is doing that but I don't know how!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you are returning only :Node and not any relationship info or :Root nodes.

One example would be to return the ids of nodes and type of relationships between them

```
MATCH (s)-[r]->(t)
RETURN id(s) as source,id(r) as target,type(r) as relationship_type
```

You can modify this query depending on what you want to export.

The whole idea is to return nodes in pairs `(source)->(destination)`. If you want to export only a specific subgraph that is connected to a specific starting node labeled :Root, you can return the graph like this:

```
MATCH (n0:Root:Node)-[:Child*0..]->(n1:Node)-[:Child]->(n2:Node)
RETURN n1, n2;
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not working. Because there's no way to tell which two nodes are connected. Please also consider that I don't know how deep the graph goes, hence the `*0..` part of the relationship selector.

Comment: source and target are always connected with the relationship pointing to target. Because i do not use any labels or relationship type in the query, it traverses the whole database and matches every relationship in the base.

Comment: With your permission, I'm going to edit your post to include what I am looking for before accepting it.

Comment: i changed your query a bit, which is better a better way of not getting the root node

Comment: That was intentional :)

Comment: In fact this is not my answer anymore!

Comment: So I am guessing you have many root nodes with isolated trees

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143633/discussion-between-mehran-and-tomaz-bratanic).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, if you have access to [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/), you can take advantage of [apoc.path.subgraphAll()](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_to_a_subgraph_and_return_all_nodes_and_relationships_within_the_subgraph), which gives you a list of all nodes in the subgraph, and all relationships between nodes in the subgraph.

```
MATCH (n0:Root)
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(n0,{relationshipFilter:'Child>'}) YIELD nodes, relationships
...
```